# Parallel foreach char array blanks

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to create a parallel foreach loop to processes a fasta file.
I've loaded the fasta file into a ConcurrentDictionary and have the parallel 
foreach setup but when I go to process the ConcurrentDictionary my char array
throws an error about being blank even though the ConcurrentDictionary value 
is never blank. I tried to debug but with the multiple threads it was very difficult
to tell what was going on.
Thank you
Casey

```
Parallel.ForEach(fastainfomation, info =>
{
    line = info.Key;
    name = info.Key;
    secondline = info.Value;

    if (name != "")
    {
        name = name.TrimEnd('\r', '\n');
        char[] secondlineprimer = secondline.ToCharArray();
        string primer = "";
        string primername = "";
        string primergroup = "";
        for (int ii = 0; ii < 8; ii++)
        {
            primer += secondlineprimer[ii];
        } ...
```

Comment: @Tudor the error is at char[] secondlineprimer = secondline.ToCharArray(); which returns a char array which is blank

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact that you're not declaring `line`, `name` etc within the lambda expression suggests that they're declared elsewhere - which means that they'll be shared by all the invocations. That in itself is enough to make your code unsafe.

You should also use `Substring` rather than repeated string concatenation like this...

```
string primer = info.Value.Substring(0, 8);
```

Beyond that, your question doesn't really contain enough information to help you further - please read [writing the perfect question](https://web.archive.org/web/20140709094611/http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) and pay more attention to clarity.

Comment: thanks this is my first time posting i'm implementing your solution and i'll post again